# git pull with www-data as user works fine in terminal but not via website

Tags: git, ubuntu, apache2

I have a script (`pull.sh`) which automatically pulls from a private git repository, which should be run when a certain webpage (`pull.php`) is opened. I am running this on an Ubuntu 20.04 server using Apache2.

`pull.sh`:

```
git -C $1 pull
```

`pull.php`:

```
<?php
    exec("/home/****/pull.sh /var/www/html/git_repository");
?>
```

Now, when running this as `www-data` with the command `sudo -u www-data php -f pull.php`, it works fine. However, when just opening the webpage, it gives an error: `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`.
Of course, I have set the credentials, so that no user name has to be entered anymore. This is also proven to work by the fact that `sudo -u www-data php -f pull.php` works.

So why does it not work when loading the webpage?

Comment: Apache is running in the fake filesystem root, that does not have sudoers.

Comment: @273K I don't see how that makes any sense in regard to my question

Answer (score 0):

You have to give permissions to the `pull.sh` file.

```
sudo chmod 777 pull.sh
```

Solved.